# Can't change hover colour of button in R shiny using custom CSS

Tags: css, r, shiny

I've written the following custom CSS file to *try* to change the colour of the buttons to dark/light grey based on whether the button is active.

```
.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #494949;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #494949;
}
.btn-primary, .btn-primary{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8f8f8f;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #8f8f8f;
}
.btn-primary.hover, .btn-primary:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8f8f8f;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #8f8f8f;
}
.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:focus{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #494949;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #494949;
}
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #494949;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #494949;
}
```

However the clicked button is still defaulting to the default dark blue. Is there some option I am missing (active/focus/default)?

I've tried targeting every element I could see in chrome developer mode.

[image: The UI once I run app]

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```r
library(shiny)
css <- "
.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #494949;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #494949;
}
"
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
  br(),
  actionButton("btn", "Button", class = "btn-primary")
)
shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {})
```

Comment: doesn't work for me - also ideally want this in a a .css script, not inline tags. I'll reask with a reproducible example - thanks anyway!